# Adding test folder to classpath for specific gradle flavour

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have android gradle project with productFlavors.

I wanted to add tests for specific flavours - they are localized in directory specific for the flavor(ie. src/envPl/java/MyTest.java). I know how to add test to test classpath:

```
sourceSets.test.java.srcDir('src/envPl/funcTest/java')
```

but how can I add this only to specific flavour?

Comment: did you try just putting it in `src/testEnvPl/java` and letting gradle do its 'magic'? This should merge `envPl` classes with `test` classes just for that flavor.

Comment: Thanks. This comment helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Build system user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies) says:

> Similar to Build Types, Product Flavors also contribute code and resources through their own sourceSets. The above example creates four sourceSets:
>
> - android.sourceSets.flavor1
>   Location `src/flavor1/`
> - android.sourceSets.flavor2
>   Location `src/flavor2/`
> - android.sourceSets.androidTestFlavor1
>   Location `src/androidTestFlavor1/`
> - android.sourceSets.androidTestFlavor2
>   Location `src/androidTestFlavor2/`

In your case, I would try

```
 android.sourceSets.androidTestFlavor1.resources.srcDir('src/envPl/funcTest/java')
```

Comment: But this would add 'src/envPl/funcTest/java' as a resource to classpath for flavor1. I want to add 'src/envPl/funcTest/java' to the java classpath *only for tests* when in flavor1.

Comment: Sorry I missed the `test` part in your question. So, you need to use the 3rd option I quoted from the docs above. Updating my answer.

Comment: I think it still doesn't answer my question. This way I'd add new Test flavor. What I'm loooking for is equivalent of
    sourceSets.test.java.srcDir('src/funcTest/java')
    sourceSets.test.resources.srcDir('src/funcTest/resources')
but only for specific flavor. So I could see those test in classpath only when in selected flavor.

Comment: You're not adding a *new* test flavor. When you add regular flavor Flavor1, android plugin automatically adds a sourceset called `androidTestFlavor1`. My answer just adds a src folder to this sourceset

Comment: You're right. I missed the part where you're supposed to let gradle do its magic. @David Medenjak comment above helped me with that. Anyway - you got bonus reputation. :)